# Unity - How can I change the draw order (to be opposite of normal draw order) of UI Objects that are childed to a Grid Layout Group

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering

In Unity Engine ~
Does anyone know how to change the draw order (to be opposite draw order) of ui elements who are children of a Grid Layout Group
So I want to keep how the elements are currently ordered positionally, but I want to change the children objects of the Grid Layout Group object to be opposite render order than usual. So instead of drawing child 0, 1, 2 (rendered ontop) - I want it child 2, 1, 0 (rendered ontop). I must emphasize, I don't want to change the actual order of the children relative to the Grid Layout Group parent game object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute way would be to create a UI material instance for each child and set queue manually.

Answer (score 1):

Add a canvas directly to the element, set overrideSorting to true and set the order manually.

Also, to make certain other things work add a graphic raycaster component

from https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/7psox8/ui_element_render_order_in_grid_layout/

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust render order using these methods:

```
transform.SetAsLastSibling (); // Element is displayed on the top.
transform.SetAsFirstSibling (); // Element is displayed last.
transform.SetSiblingIndex (7); // Element is displayed based on an index
transform.GetSiblingIndex ();
```